# Connecting blocks in a block diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Is it possible to connect this diagram:

[image]

like this diagram:

[image]

Here is the code for the diagram:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}    

% \usetikzlibrary{positioning}  
% \usepackage{subfig} 
% \usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{float}

\title{Diagramas} 
\author{}
\date{}

% Modificaciones 
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em   ]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]   
% \tikzstyle{system} = [draw, fill=gray!50, rectangle, 
%     minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em   ]

% \tikzset{system/.style={shape=circle,draw,minimum size=1.2cm, draw=blue!80, fill=blue!20, text centered, align=center}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{figure}[H]\centering 
\hspace*{-3cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex',anchor=center]
%Declara los nodos  
\node[block, fill = gray!50] (system) {$\begin{array}{cc} \text{\textbf{Sistema de}}\\ \text{\textbf{Bola Balanza}} \end{array}$};     
\node[block, below of = system, fill = black, left = 7.5cm] (end){\textcolor{white}{Bola Balanza}};

\node[block, below of = system, left = 1.9cm](data1){$\begin{array}{cc} \text{\small{Experimentos}}\\ \text{\small{sin perturbaciones}} \end{array}$};
\node[block, below of = system, left = -1.65cm](data2){$\begin{array}{cc} \text{\small{Experimentos}}\\ \text{\small{con perturbaciones}} \end{array}$};
\node[block, below of = system, right = 2cm](data3){\small{Comparación teórica}}; 

\node[block, below of = end, left = 1.6cm, fill = gray!50](ss1){$\begin{array}{cc} \text{Diseño}\\ \text{de la planta} \end{array}$};
\node[block, below of = end, left = -1.4cm, fill = gray!50](ss2){\footnotesize{Diseño del software}};
\node[block, below of = end, right = 1.6cm, fill = gray!50](ss3){Modelado};

%Ahora conectamos los bloques 
\draw[-] (system) -| (data1);
\draw[-] (system) -- (data2); 
\draw[-] (system) -| (data3);

\draw[-] (system) -| (end);

\draw[-] (end) -| (ss1);
\draw[-] (end) -- (ss2);
\draw[-] (end) -| (ss3);


\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{Sistema Bola Balanza}
\end{figure} 


\begin{figure}[H]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex',anchor=center]  
\hspace*{0cm}


\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Modelado}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: the first part of your requirement is in the answer below -- is this what is desired or did you have something different in mind -- there is a change in the code -- `below=of node` and not `below of=node` -- the `calc` library is used to move the point of origin at `system.south` to right by `6pt` and then down by `3ex` -- also the arrows are not used so no need of the `>=latex'` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows, positioning, calc}    
\usepackage{float}

\title{Diagramas} 
\author{}
\date{}

% Modificaciones 
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em   ]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]   

\begin{document}
    
        \begin{tikzpicture}[,node distance=2em]
            %Declara los nodos  
            \node[block, fill = gray!50] (system) {$\begin{array}{cc} \text{\textbf{Sistema de}}\\ \text{\textbf{Bola Balanza}} \end{array}$};
                 
            \node[block, below=of system, ](data1){$\begin{array}{cc} \text{\small{Experimentos}}\\ \text{\small{sin perturbaciones}} \end{array}$};
            
            \node[block, right=of data1 = system, ](data2){$\begin{array}{cc} \text{\small{Experimentos}}\\ \text{\small{con perturbaciones}} \end{array}$};
            
            \node[block, right=of data2 ](data3){\small{Comparación teórica}}; 
            
            %Ahora conectamos los bloques 
            \draw[] ($(system.south)+(6ex,0pt)$)coordinate(aux) --++(0pt,-3ex)-|(data1);
            \draw[] (aux) --++(0pt,-3ex)-|(data2);
            \draw[] (aux) --++(0pt,-3ex)-|(data3);
    
        \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```